# Boruvka algorithm parallel implementation CUDA

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, cuda, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm trying to implement [Boruvka's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm) for Minimum Spanning Trees in CUDA. I understand the basic logic, but I'm having trouble implementing it. The algorithm is:

```
Initialize Graph G(V,E)
Initialize MST
while size(G) > 1:
  for all nodes in graph:
    min equals minimum outgoing edge
    ?
```

After I compute the minimum outgoing edges for each node, I don't understand how to reduce the disjoint subgraphs into new nodes. Once I do that, how do I compute the minimum edges between these disjoint subgraphs?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to reduce the disjoint subgraphs into new nodes, you just have to recompute for each node its new component to be able to distinguish(during the computation of minimum outgoing edges) if the node belongs to different component. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) data structure will help you to do that in effective way.

For the computation of the minimum edges between disjoint subgraphs the [reduction](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reduction+cuda) is usually used. I think you will have to launch another kernel for this.